# Private conda channels for anaconda python

Tags: python, package, conda

I have been usng anaconda python for a long time now and have had a really good experience with it.  I have a need to work on an air gapped network and so have tried to create a private channel with the necessary packages so that I and my team can install them as needed without access to the internet.  Here is what I have tried:

1) Install anaconda (5.2) from the bash shell script (fresh install)
2) Install all necessary packages using the command

conda install --file requirements.txt

3) Create a directory AnacondaChannel/linux-64 and copy all the *.bz2 files from the pkgs directory in the new install into linux-64.
4) Issue the command

conda index AnacondaChannel

5) Create the directory AnacondaChannel/noarch and add an empty, bzipped, json file in it per the instructions for channel instantiation
6) As a test I then do a fresh install of anaconda python as in step (1) above and issue the command

conda install -c file://AnacondaChannel --override-channels --file requirements.txt

The install then happens and all is well -- except -- that for some combinations of packages that installed just fine when connected to the internet I get an unresolvable conflict error with a few packages listed as having a conflict.  It seems that this should not be the case as I collected --all-- the packages in the pkgs directory.  Is there a method for accomplishing this that I haven't been able to find in the documentation?  As always, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I should perhaps clarify -- all is well-- sometimes. Other times, depending on the combination of packages I am trying to put in the channel, the local install errors out complaining about some combination of packages having an unresolvable conflict.  This is the case, even though they apparently had no conflict when installed using full repos on the internet.