# Stages for Conda environment.yml

Tags: python, conda, conda-build

I'm trying to reduce the build time for my package's test stage on Azure. My `environment.yml` which is used by `conda` contains all required dependencies: core, test and docs dependencies.

For the testing stage I would like to skip docs dependencies as they aren't necessary, but I want to keep each dependency defined only in one place (so a separate `environment-docs.yml` that repeats all core and test packages with their versions is not acceptable).

Ideally, I would like a functionality similar to docker stages, hypothetically:

`environment.yml`

```yaml
name: lorem-ipsum
channels:
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  core:
    - numpy
    - scipy
  test:
    - pytest
  docs:
    - sphinx
```

```
conda env create --file environment.yml --stage test
```

Then it would solve and install all packages up to the `test` section.

I didn't find a solution how to achieve something similar without repeating all core dependencies in separate `environment.yml` files.

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: The `conda create` command supports multiple files. It takes the requirements.txt format, like what comes out of `conda list --export`.

Answer (score 0):

Your question looks more like a feature request to Conda which you can [raise here](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/new/choose).

Also, it seems that you have separate modules with documentation only? This is non-typical. Binaries come along with documentation together. So it would be not easy to distinguish between the installed modules with and without documentation unless you created a "stripped" version of the modules yourself. Then just point to such a [custom Conda channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53788509/private-conda-channels-for-anaconda-python). It would probably be a lot of work (unless you concentrate on the largest packages).